# I can't find how to reproducibly run a Python gymnasium taxi-v3 environment

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm using Gymnasium library (https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/Gymnasium) for some research in reinforcement learning algorithms.

Gymnasium is the actual development of the old Gym library (https://github.com/openai/gym).

I want to reproducibly run a Python Gymnasium environment "taxi-v3".

What is usually done is to pass a seed to the random number generators involved.

But, even doing things like this:

```
import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np
import random

seed = 42

random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

env = gym.make("Taxi-v3")
state, info = env.reset(seed=seed)
```

I couldn't reach my goal.

What am I not understanding?

What is missing?

Comment: Each time you execute the code; the variable "state" will be initialized with the same value. You have therefore a reproducible environment. (You don't need the addition number generators '"random" and "np.random" here/with gym).
Remove the argument and use just "env.reset()" and the initial state of the env will be vary.

Comment: @MarcelFlygare , I did this "import gymnasium as gym ; env = gym.make("Taxi-v3") ; state, info = env.reset(); print(state)", and each time I run the script I get a diferent state. I'm with Python 3.8.16 and gymnasium==0.28.1.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. You can fix the seed as you have done in your question.  (Does it solve your problem ? I might not have understood it)

Comment: @Marcel Flygare , no. Fix the seed does not solve my problem. And that's why my question. I need the result to be reproducible. It would also solve my problem if I could specifically indicate what state I want to reset the environment to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like stated in the comments under OP, this is expected behaviour. Setting `random.seed()` and `np.random.seed()` does not have any effect on the environment. Generating the environment with a specific `seed` makes the environment reproducable: i.e. the environment consisting of an observation space, action space, transition function, reward function, and an initial state distribution remain the same under a static seed.

```py
import gymnasium as gym

seed = 42

env = gym.make("Taxi-v3")
state, info = env.reset(seed=seed)
print(state, info)
```

yields

```py
>> 386 {'prob': 1.0, 'action_mask': array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int8)}
```

each time you generate the environment with `seed=42`.

Now, if your model/policy you use to pick actions via a certain observation is deterministic, then the code is reproducable. Note that if you are training your model/policy on an environment with a fixed seed, it may not perform well on other seeds. I would not recommend training it on a fixed seed.

What an approach would be, is to train your model on various seeds (i.e. not fixed), and save your model. Then, if you import your model to use it on the environment and see the performance, you can fix the seed on your environment. Since the model is trained and picks actions, if set so, deterministically, and the environment then uses a fixed seed, the environment is reproducable.

Comment: I don't know why my code, in question, didn't give me reproducible environment before when I asked the question. Testing now not only your code, but also mine, quoted above, are working reproducibly, always returning the same state. Again, I don't understand what happened here. But thanks, your answer is correct. And also the comment from @MarcelFlygare.